# How can I programmatically set the app to handle an Intent parsed from a url?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following url -> https://www.jiosaavn.com/s/featured/hindi/chill_maaro/CZTTBas4j8RieSJqt9HmOQ__

When I try to launch this using the following code :

```
context = LocalContext.current
var jioURL = "https://www.jiosaavn.com/s/featured/hindi/chill_maaro/CZTTBas4j8RieSJqt9HmOQ__"
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(jioURL))
context.startActivity(launchIntent)
```

I get a popup which asks me to choose one of the two apps that can handle this intent. Is there some way to avoid this popup and just choose one of the two app to open this intent from my code?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, all I had to do was use

```
intent.setpackage("packagename")
```